# How to exclude child nodes with XPath selector?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have the following HTML fragment:

```
<div class="d1">
 <p> 
   text
 <br/>
 <div class="d2"> text </div>
 ...
 <a class="a1">a1</a>  
 <a class="a2">a2</a>
</div>
```

I want to get the content of `d1` class and also exclude `a1` and `a2` classes using this:

```
//div[contains(@class, "d1") and (@class!="a1") and (@class!="a2")]
```

but this failed.

How can I write the selector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XPath is for selection**, not for transformation.  (XSLT is for transformation.)

You can select `div` elements that do not contain certain `a` elements ***only if the `div` elements already exist in the input document***; you cannot select `div` elements and then remove child elements once selected.

Comment: thanks.i figured reason out.but in this situation, how can i get my desired result?no means with xpath selector?

Comment: You're welcome.  Right, XPath can't do this.  Consider another tool such as XSLT or an XML parsing library combined with your favorite programming language. Thanks.